# Custom mean IoU metric to train a U-Net model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a custom mean IoU metric for training a U-Net model to classify four classed [0, 1, 2, 3] dataset but I get an error.

My code:

```py
#Calculating mean IoU metric

from keras.metrics import MeanIoU
from keras import backend as K
n_classes = 4

def mean_IoU_metric(y_true, y_pred):

    y_pred_argmax = K.argmax(y_true, axis=3) 
    IOU_keras = MeanIoU(num_classes=n_classes)  
    IOU_keras.update_state(y_true[:,:,:,0], y_pred_argmax)
    IOU_keras = tf.convert_to_tensor(IOU_keras, np.float32)

    return IOU_keras
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Expected float32, but got MeanIoU(name=mean_io_u,dtype=float32,num_classes=4) of type 'MeanIoU'.
```

Would you please help me to solve this issue and thank you very much.

Comment: In what context are you using the `IOU_keras`?

Comment: Im trying to use it a as metric for  training U-Net model on dataset consist of for regions (4 classes), I'm  already using accuracy but want improve the results further by mean IoU.

Comment: I understand that, but to see the error in action you need to share the lines where the object is being used.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I guess I solved this problem but now facing another problem about using (sparse_categorical_crossentropy) because the train results are not improving at all and stay the same without any change, could you please help me to understand why this happening. Thanks a lot:

Comment: The training results is not changing as following: Epoch 1/50
40/40 [==============================] - 11s 217ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1299 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1299 - my_mean_iou_1: 1.0000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1270 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1270 - val_my_mean_iou_1: 1.0000
Epoch 2/50
40/40 [==============================] - 8s 199ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1299 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1299 - my_mean_iou_1: 1.0000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.1270 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1270 - val_my_mean_iou_1: 1.0000

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use meanIoU (average IoU across multiple samples) as a metric during and after training a model in TensorFlow, you can follow the solution provided below.

1. Create a custom metric class that inherits from `tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU`

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class CustomMeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
    """
    Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32875#issuecomment-707316950
    """
    def __init__(self, num_classes=None, name=None, dtype=None):
        super(CustomMeanIoU, self).__init__(
            num_classes=num_classes, name=name, dtype=dtype
        )

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.math.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
        y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```

2. To use this metric during model training, do the following:

```py
custom_mIoU_metric = CustomMeanIoU(num_classes=4, name='mIoU')

model.compile(
    ...,
    metrics=[custom_mIoU_metric]
)
```

Depending on your project it may need slight modifications. You can find a working example in my personal project: https://github.com/MortenTabaka/Semantic-segmentation-of-LandCover.ai-dataset/blob/main/src/features/metrics.py